# F3 on Windows is what on a Mac?

Tags: mac, search, windows

On Windows to quickly search something, I just press <kbd>F3</kbd> and then you can type what you are searching for as "keywords", how do you do this on Mac? I am busy with HTML and I want to quickly search something.

Answer (score 12):

In general, to search for something on a Mac, **Spotlight** is what's used and can be brought up pressing: <kbd>Command (⌘)</kbd>-<kbd>Space bar</kbd>

Have a look at: [OS X Yosemite: Spotlight keyboard shortcuts](https://support.apple.com/kb/PH18799?locale=en_US)

If in an application, like **TextEdit** as an example, pressing <kbd>⌘</kbd><kbd>F</kbd> brings up Find.

Also have a look at: [Mac keyboard shortcuts](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201236)

Answer (score 3):

You can use <kbd>Command</kbd> + <kbd>F</kbd> to search within Safari, Preview or most OS X applications..